# Durandal splash screen when working with promises

Tags: durandal

My durandal based SPA makes various async ajax calls in the activate function of the viewmodels. I am returning a promise using Q from the activate function.

```
 function activate(){
      return Q.fcall(['getPersons', 'getAgenda']);
 }

 function getPersons(){
      var defer = Q.defer();
      $.ajax({
         //omitting most of the settings
         success: function(data){
              defer.resolve(data);
         },
         error: function(xhr, status){
              defer.reject(status);
         }
      });

     return defer.promise; 
 }
```

Similar code exists in the getAgenda function too. All this works fine and my screen transitions in. The trouble is, my getAgenda takes a while (2 to 3 seconds). The splash screen does not appear, the screen stays where it was for the 2 or 3 seconds before transitioning in.

my splash screen is simple and does show the very first time the site loads. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your splash screen looks similiar to http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Adding-a-Splash-Screen, then this is meant as a one time splash screen that gets overwritten in `app.start`.

```
<div id="applicationHost">
    <div class="splash">
        <div class="message">
            Durandal Starter Kit
        </div>
        <i class="icon-spinner icon-2x icon-spin active"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

You're probably looking for some kind of loading indicator. E.g in samples this is implemented based on `router.isNavigating`, so in you vm create similiar `isLoading` observable, which you set to true before the async call and to false when done.

https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2/blob/gh-pages/App/samples/shell.html#L13

```
<div class="loader pull-right" data-bind="css: { active: router.isNavigating }">
    <i class="icon-spinner icon-2x icon-spin"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to integrate [Pacejs](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) into durandal navigation, and it ended up pretty easy thanks to router.isNavigating

Here is the gist https://gist.github.com/volak/4aca442373b4216a52b5